# Equivalence Relations in Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let S be the relation on the set of ordered pairs of positive integers such that ((a,b),(c,d)) ∈ S if and only if ac = bd. Show that S is not an equivalence relation.

So far I got:

Let (a,b) ∈ A,
Since ab=ba, ((a,b),(b,a)) ∈ S, therefore, S is reflexive.

Now let ((a,b),(c,d)) ∈ S, ac = bd -> bd = ac -> db = ca. This implies ((d,b),(c,a)) ∈ S. Therefore, S is not symmetric.

Any issues with this? Do I need to show any more work? Thanks!

Comment: given $((a,b),(c,d))\in S$, the issue of symmetry is whether $((c,d),(a,b))\in S$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof for non-symmetry isn't valid since there's multiple conclusions to be had.

Suppose $((a,b),(c,d)) \in S$. Then $ac=bd$. Equivalently, $ca=db$ since multiplication commutes. Therefore $((c,d),(a,b)) \in S$, giving symmetry. That other pairs are implied to be in $S$ isn't relevant.

More generally, $R$ is a symmetric relation if $(a,b) \in R \implies (b,a) \in R$.

---

So, we know the relation $S$ is reflexive and symmetric... If it's truly not an equivalence, it must not be transitive.

Except it's not reflexive.

If it is, then $((a,b),(a,b)) \in S$. But then $a^2 = b^2$. Does this always hold?

Comment: So using your example of a^2 = b^2, it would imply that this is not symmetric since this would only be true if both a and b are equal?

Comment: Correct. Consider, for a more explicit example, $(3,4)$. It is not related to itself since $9 \ne 16$, and therefore $((3,4),(3,4) \not \in S$.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say "is not reflexive" rather than symmetric. Also, just to help me understand this better, could you use the same reasoning for non-reflexivity if S is the relation on the set of ordered pairs of positive integers such that ((a,b),(c,d)) are in S if and only if ad=bc (rather than ac=bd like in my original question)?

Comment: It was would be a similar line of reasoning, but quite a different conclusion. Let $S$ be your proposed alternative relation on $\Bbb Z^+ \times \Bbb Z^+$. Is $(a,b)S(a,b)$ true? The condition for this is $ab=ba$, which is true since multiplication commutes after all.